# How to save console result into an new column? in r

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I have a df with 38 columns and 405 rows.

In the last 30 columns there are integer values saved. I want to sum them up into a new column.

The console result is right but I don't know how to safe it into a new column in the same df.

```
df %>% 
  replace(is.na(.), 0) %>% 
   mutate(sum = rowSums(.[9:38]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can assign

```
df1 <- df %>% 
  replace(is.na(.), 0) %>% 
   mutate(sum = rowSums(.[9:38]))
```

---

Or make this more dyanmic

```
df1 <- df %>%
         mutate(sum = rowSums(select(cur_data(), 
                    where(is.integer)), na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Poblem with `mutate()` column `sum`.
i `sum = rowSums(.[9:38])`.
x undefined columns selected                                                                                        
 This is the error I recieve now once I used your aproach. Do you have another Idea?

Comment: @Paul In your description, it says that `the console result is right but I don´t know how to safe it into a new collumn in the same df.`  I just copied your code and assign it to the same data

Comment: @Paul I added one more method.  Not sure why your code worked and mine didn't work when we use the same code

Comment: sorry akrun, your was right! I missed that you safed as an ne df1